# NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY writing in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

What could be the cause of this exception in Firefox when I write in localStorage?

Here is the function which writes in localStorage:

```
try {
        localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(data);
    } catch(e) {
     .... // CODE TU PRINT THE ERROR
    }
```

FYI, I set the storageQuota of Firefox to a ridiculiously high number in order to save a lot of data, because the default value is very low for my purpose.

If anyone can help or need more information just comment or ask.
Thanks!

Comment: I dont think your issue is with local storage.  Your data might have circular references causing the JSON string to blow up.  What happens if you call `JSON.stringify(data)` without writing it to local storage?  Does it actually generate a string, and if so, how big is it?

Comment: This is the length of one data I'm trying to save now: 22392130, but now for example the exception didn't happen. It only takes place sometimes, and once it happen one time, if I don't restart Firefox it'll happen every time I execute that code.

Comment: What happens if you call JSON.stringify(data) without writing it to local storage? Do you *ever* get the error?

Comment: I'm writing in localStorage sometimes in two tabs at the same time, could be an error of threading?

Comment: Can you first respond to the question I've asked *twice*?  Why would you think an OUT OF MEMORY ERROR indicates a threading issue?

Comment: As you suspected, the error is in the JSON.stringify call. I'm working to divide that huge JSON I'm saving now into pieces.

Comment: Okay, I have written an answer.  Without knowing your object structure, I can only guess at recommended solutions, but I've faced a similar thing before.  I would try the *replacer* arg I mentioned.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't with local storage at all.  An `NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` indicates you're out of *memory*.  Exceeding your browser's local storage quota would result in a `QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR` (or equivalent) error.

You're getting an out of memory error because your `JSON.stringify(...)` call is way too big to fit into memory.

You can either

- a) split your object up into smaller pieces, and stringify each separately.  Alone, this *may* not be sufficient to solve your problem.  It depends on why your JSON is so huge.
- b) Use an overload of [`JSON.stringify(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with the *replacer* argument.  See the documentation for proper usage.  You can 'trim' unnecessary data out of your JSON and handle any circular references.

Here's the thing, if you have a huge object and that object is referenced dozens of times, that object will appear in your JSON *dozens of times*.  In other words, as an object it exists in memory *once*, but when serialized, the object gets serialized over and over again.  That inflates your JSON.  Taking out that object, turning it into its own JSON, and replacing references to it with an ID can shrink your JSON dramatically.  The *replacer* argument can be used to do this, if needed or desired.

Comment: Splitting the huge variable in more small pieces did the trick, the error dissapeared.